# CoreData NSPredicate date() function

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to use the following predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ending_date < date('now')", nil];
```

But I'm getting `NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse function name 'date:' into supported selector (date:) '` so I guess maybe the `date('now')` is not supported on **iOS** version of **SQLite**

how can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this...

```
NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ending_date < %@", dateNow];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the NSExpression now instead of date:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ending_date < now", nil];
```